# bin/rails generate model error, bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rubygems, development-environment

I'm setting up a rails environment, following instructions from this:

Copy, paste, and run the following, one line at a time:

```
sudo rvm implode
```

If it says sudo: rvm: command not found, that's fine.

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm
brew ls --versions rbenv
```

If nothing shows up after you run "brew ls --versions rbenv", copy, paste, and run the following:

```
brew install rbenv
brew install ruby-build
```

Copy, paste, and run:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

In the text editor:

Search (command+F) for "rvm", and delete any lines that have it.
Copy and paste the following at the bottom:
  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

Save and quit.
Copy, paste, and run:

```
rbenv install 2.1.2
rbenv global 2.1.2
```

and then going through this tutorial
http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html

Now I'm just trying to run the `bin/rails generate model` command from my project dir and I'm getting this error

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/me/Desktop/DevProjects/blogger/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I see other questions with 'generate' causing problems, but none with my specific error. All I could surmise was that it seemd like I was missing a gem called 'bundler/setup' so I did installed that. Now, using the same comamnd `bin/rails generate model Article`, it told me that I didn't have rake, so  I did gem install rake, and then it said I don't have 'i18n' and then I realized its just going through the gems that weer installed with 'bundler' one by one.

I feel like something is going on that is completely beyonod the scope of my understanding of how the PATH works, program environments, etc.

Comment: gem install bundler  && bundle in the project directory should fix it

Comment: @Doon not sure if this would have worked, but i did a clean reinstall of rails, bundle and bundler which solved my issues.